# How do I embed a CiviCRM page into a wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page, integration

I'm new to this and trying to get my head around the integration with wordpress.
I'm having problems using CiviCRM to integrate with wordpress. I set up a civicontributions page with membership dues etc but when i try to follow the documentation to embed the contribution page into my wordpress page. The documentation asks me to "Click on the CiviCRM icon next to Upload / Insert" but no such icon is available for me, nor do I see an Upload/Insert button.

I've installed WordPress 5.1.1 and CiviCRM 5.13.1
i've disabled all plugins except for CiviCRM and tried different themes.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you very much
best regards,
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the new block editor... in this case you don't see the civicrm button. Easiest solution is to switch to the classic editor. I think the documentation needs updating. Once you know what the shortcodes look like you could just type them in (you would need to know the contribution id)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help. that does the trick.